# how to write query for lead getting more than one field?

Tags: apex

I am writing apex class for retrieve deleted records using rest api. I used this query :

```
"https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/queryAll/?q=SELECT+lastname+from+lead+WHERE+isDeleted+=+True"
```

By using this i am getting all records but i need firstname,lastname,company fields i tried :

```
 "https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/queryAll/?q=SELECT+firstname+lastname+company+from+lead+WHERE+isDeleted+=+True"
```

but i m getting error:

```
 "message": "only aggregate expressions use field aliasing",
    "errorCode": "MALFORMED_QUERY"
```

Please help on this writing query for lead

Comment: You need to separate the list of fieldnames by commas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Separate field names by commas:

```
"https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/queryAll/?q=SELECT+firstname,+lastname+company+from+lead+WHERE+isDeleted+=+True"
```